# GridView Centering Issues

Tags: html, asp.net, css

How can I center the text of the rows of an `<asp:GridView />` that gets populated at run-time?

I have tried `RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"` and similar things that I have found in this site to no avail.

Similarly, I cannot center a `GridView` inside a `div`—that is, `<div><asp:GridView /></div>`—to save my life.

Am I using a bunch of deprecated functions or what? Also, Chrome is my default browser.

I am aware that a thousand questions in the gist of mine have been asked before, but all that I have tried are either years old or are not working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Centered in a div horizontally or vertically?

Comment: I mean horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using bound columns or autogenerated?  If you're binding them in your markup, something like this should work fine (this is an actual example from something of mine):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="External Id" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtExternalId" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ExternalId")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewExternalId" runat="server" Width="100%" />
    </FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblExternalId" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ExternalId")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Also -- try using ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign rather than RowStyle-HorizontalAlign, see if that achieves what you want (as you can see in my example above)